# how to send registration id with image using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to upload an image but I also want to send an ID related to that image. Here I am able to send image but not ID.

```
$("#upload").on('click', function() {
  var imgData = document.getElementById("fileBrowser").files[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("file",imgData);

  $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    method: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("unsuccess");
    }
  });
});
```

```php
if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] !='')
{
  $test = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($test);
  $random = rand(100,999);
  $image_name = $random.".".$extension;
  $location = "upimages/".$image_name;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
}
```

Comment: _“Help, I am not able to call `form_data.append` a second time”_ ...?

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `append()` the required to the `FormData` object, just as you do with the file:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", imgData);   
form_data.append('id', 'your value here');
```

You can then retrieve the value in your PHP code using `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: Not closing as "typo"?

Comment: Not sure how this would count as a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to store both your form_data, and your ID:

```
var dataToSend = {};
dataToSend.form_data = form_data;
dataToSend.yourID = yourID;
```

then send dataToSend:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"url",
    method:"POST",
    data:**dataToSend**,
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data){
        alert("success");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("unsuccess");
    }
});
```

Comment: This method won't work for binary data. Everything needs to be placed in the FormData object, not serialised.